# Trying to Implement MapTree in terms of FoldTree

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

Trying to implement a mapTree in terms of foldTree.

```
data Tree a = Leaf   | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) deriving Show
```

foldTree is shown here

```
foldTree :: b -> (b -> a -> b -> b) -> Tree a -> b
foldTree l n Leaf           = l
foldTree l n (Node lt x rt) = n (foldTree l n lt) x (foldTree l n rt)
```

This is what I have so far for mapTree so far but I'm relatively new to haskell and I'm not sure where to go from here

```
mapTree :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
mapTree f = foldTree Leaf (\x t1 t2 -> Node (f x) t1 t2)
```

Comment: look closely to how the things are ordered: `Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)` ; `(b -> a -> b -> b)` ; `n (foldTree l n lt) x (foldTree l n rt)` ; ====> `n = (\ ..... -> Node .....(f x)..... ) `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this is an exercise / homework and only give you a nudge:

This `Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)` is:

1. a left Tree
2. a payload value of type `a`.
3. a right Tree

**in this order**. And here `(\x t1 t2 -> Node (f x) t1 t2)` you construct a -value- (edit: Node!) out of

1. something that looks / is named like a value `f x`
2. tree1
3. tree2

**in that order**.

Addressing the follow-up `updated to mapTree f = foldTree Leaf (Node (f x) (\x t1 t2 -> t1 t2))`: The "and here" above was deliberately vague, so lets have a look at

```
foldTree :: b -> (b -> a -> b -> b) -> Tree a -> b
--          1    \_______2________/       3      4
```

This takes:

1. a value of type `b` for `Leafs`
2. a combining function that takes:

   1. the result of the folded left tree `b`
   2. the value of the currently folded Node `a`
   3. the result of the folded right tree `b`
   4. and outputs a `b`
3. the tree to be folded.

in this order. Your function `(\x t1 t2 -> Node (f x) t1 t2)` in place of 2 takes

1. the value of the currently folded Node `a`
2. the result of the folded left tree `b`
3. the result of the folded right tree `b`
4. and outputs a `b`

in that order.

So all you have to do is correct the order of both sides of the `->` in `(\x t1 t2 -> Node (f x) t1 t2)`.

Comment: I've updated to

mapTree f = foldTree Leaf (Node (f x) (\x t1 t2 -> t1 t2))

Is my implementation close? I see you say tree1 and tree 2 instead of left and right I'm guessing that part is totally wrong?